# eloquent model with empty primary key value

Tags: php, eloquent, slim-3

I'm using Slim 3 with Eloquent as ORM. I have a product table that contains only 3 fields, productCode, name and price. I am having problems to obtain an attribute of my products.

I have created a model class for products, it is the following:

```
class Product extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'productCode';

    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'price'
    ];
}
```

Esta la estoy utilizando desde mi controlador para enviarlos como Json, de la siguiente forma:

```
class ProductsController extends Controller
{

    public function getAll($request, $response)
    {
        $products = Product::all();

        return $response->withJson($products, 200);
    }
}
```

The problem is that it returns the following:

```
[{"productCode":0,"name":"producto 1","price":15000},{"productCode":0,"name":"producto 2","price":20000},{"productCode":0,"name":"producto 3","price":5999}]
```

all the productCode variables are changed by vacuum, so json returns 0.

when reviewing the variable with print_r(), it does contain the productCode correctly, but I have not been able to obtain those values, it always returns empty.

```
    Store\Models\Product Object
(
    [primaryKey:protected] => productCode
    [timestamps] => 
    [fillable:protected] => Array
        (
            [0] => name
            [1] => price
        )

    [connection:protected] => default
    [table:protected] => 
    [keyType:protected] => int
    [incrementing] => 1
    [with:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [withCount:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [perPage:protected] => 15
    [exists] => 1
    [wasRecentlyCreated] => 
    [attributes:protected] => Array
        (
            [productCode] => cod0001
            [name] => producto 1
            [price] => 15000
        )

    [original:protected] => Array
        (
            [productCode] => cod0001
            [name] => producto 1
            [price] => 15000
        )

    [changes:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [casts:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [dates:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [dateFormat:protected] => 
    [appends:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [dispatchesEvents:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [observables:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [relations:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [touches:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [hidden:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [visible:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [guarded:protected] => Array
        (
            [0] => *
        )

)
```

As you can see, if the variable contains the correct productCode, the problem is that they remain empty when I try to obtain them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to tell Eloquent that the primary key isn't auto-incrementing:

```
class Product extends Model
{
    public $incrementing = false;
}
```